# How to fix grid layout extending body element, I mean grid width becomes larger than body width

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Please help!
I've placed some layouts in my file, wrapped in this grid...

```
<div class"col-auto col-sm-10 col-md-7 col-lg-7> </div>
```

The grid is responsive until at 576px, below that width it not responsive.
The grid has:
card with width set to 50%,
image with width set to 25%,
some paragraphs in card-body and
text in card-footer

Comment: this should be <div class="col-auto col-sm-10 col-md-7 col-lg-7"> </div>, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each col classes should be in its own respective div, wrapped in row class:
So instead of this:

```
<div class = "col-auto col-sm-10 col-md-7 col-lg-7"> </div> (fixed typo)
```

Try this and see if it works:

```html
<div class="row">
<div class="col-auto"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-10"></div>
<div class="col-sm-7"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-10"></div>
<div class="col-lg-7"></div>
</div>
```

Also, the numbers in the row should add up to 12 in total otherwise, it won't behave as you expected.
You can check out their documentation about the grid system [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/grid/).

Comment: Thanks! Lemme try it.. I'll give you feedback